# Combine two or more columns into one in a table

Tags: sql-server, data-structures, combinations

I have an existing database with a table that I need to alter. Due to some recent changes requested, I need to take two columns out of a table and put the data from those two columns into an existing column in the table. Thankfully, they are all Varchar type so the data doesn't have to be transformed.

Here's what the table looks like now:
[image]

And here's what I want it to be:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure where to even start with this. So what's the best way to do this without breaking the table or losing any data?

NOTE: This is NOT for querying. I want to change the structure of the table itself to remove these two columns but take their data and dump it into an existing column.

Comment: I have to ask why? First table is much better you can do what ever you want with her in the other hand the structure of second table can  cause you a headache... I would understand if you want to do this in other direction... GL!

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic I need to combine the three values because they have been combined on the form that this table is related to. These three columns were simply for three different types of comments on the form but now they have combined all comments into one field on the form so it's much easier to combine those three columns into one column at the database level for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by a simple update statement:

```
Update table
Set colC = colC + char(13) + char(10) + colD +char(13) + char(10) + colE
```

Note that `char(13) + char(10)` is a line break.

After you verify that the data was copied, use alter table to drop colD and colE.

The question is **are you sure this move is wise?**

This move seem to contredict a basic rule of relational databases design. If these columns stores different data entities I would strongly recommend against such a move.
Unless these values actually needs to be merged into a single value (on the logical level) then this is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I have to agree with Zohar. While this fine example will work you are ruining your database by violating 1NF. Don't store more than 1 value in a single intersection of a table. What a mess you will have when you need to update this or find rows that have only 1 of those other values.

Comment: Windows line breaks are the other way around—`char(13) + char(10)`—so that's probably what I'd use. Different programs will interpret `char(10) + char(13)` differently. That said, +1 for "Are you sure this move is wise?" :)

Comment: Wow that was much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you.

The reason I am combining the three columns into one is because the form that this table is related to has changed and it has combined three different fields into one field. And I was told to do the same with the table in the database to keep the values from the columns that are supposed to be removed now. I could technically still keep the two columns and make all the new entries just go to one column but I don't see the point in doing that.

Comment: @joe thanks for the fix, I always get them in the wrong order... using `\n` is simpler...

Comment: @david: if the values are merged into a single vlaue, and not as an attempt to create an array-like column then you should merge them on the database level as well.